# Parallel for loop in openmp

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a very simple for-loop, but this is my first attempt at using openMP in a long time. I'm getting baffled by the run times. Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    int n=400000,  m=1000;  
    double x=0,y=0;
    double s=0;
    vector< double > shifts(n,0);


    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {

        double r=0.0;
        for (int i=0; i < m; i++){

            double rand_g1 = cos(i/double(m));
            double rand_g2 = sin(i/double(m));     

            x += rand_g1;
            y += rand_g2;
            r += sqrt(rand_g1*rand_g1 + rand_g2*rand_g2);
        }
        shifts[j] = r / m;
    }

    cout << *std::max_element( shifts.begin(), shifts.end() ) << endl;
}
```

I compile it with

```
g++ -O3 testMP.cc -o testMP  -I /opt/boost_1_48_0/include
```

that is, no "-fopenmp", and I get these timings:

```
real    0m18.417s
user    0m18.357s
sys     0m0.004s
```

when I do use "-fopenmp",

```
g++ -O3 -fopenmp testMP.cc -o testMP  -I /opt/boost_1_48_0/include
```

I get these numbers for the times:

```
real    0m6.853s
user    0m52.007s
sys     0m0.008s
```

which doesn't make sense to me. How using eight cores can only result in just 3-fold 
 increase of performance? Am I coding the loop correctly?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should make use of the OpenMP `reduction` clause for `x` and `y`:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:x,y)
for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {

    double r=0.0;
    for (int i=0; i < m; i++){

        double rand_g1 = cos(i/double(m));
        double rand_g2 = sin(i/double(m));     

        x += rand_g1;
        y += rand_g2;
        r += sqrt(rand_g1*rand_g1 + rand_g2*rand_g2);
    }
    shifts[j] = r / m;
}
```

With `reduction` each thread accumulates its own partial sum in `x` and `y` and in the end all partial values are summed together in order to obtain the final values.

```
Serial version:
25.05s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 25.059 total
OpenMP version w/ OMP_NUM_THREADS=16:
24.76s user 0.02s system 1590% cpu 1.559 total
```

See - superlinear speed-up :)

Comment: so in order to reduce the time that is lost by the barrier making sync, the reduction clause will accumulate results in intermediate variables so that sync is made only at the end and only once?

Comment: @sam yes, you can create local variables for the partial sums and manually reduce them at the end. As this is a very common pattern in parallel programming, the `reduction` clause is a convenient shortcut that lets OpenMP do it for you. In that particular case, `x` and `y` are shared variables and must not be written by multiple threads at the same time as this both creates issues with correctness and also trashes the cache.

Answer (score 34):

let's try to understand how parallelize simple for loop using OpenMP

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
    for(i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
       c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
```

assume that we have `3` available threads, this is what will happen

[image]

firstly

- Threads are assigned an independent set of iterations

and finally

- Threads must wait at the end of work-sharing construct

Answer (score 17):

**Because this question is highly viewed I decided to add a bit a OpenMP background to help those visiting it**

---

The `#pragma omp parallel` creates a **parallel region** with a team of `threads`, where each thread executes the entire block of code that the `parallel region` encloses.
From the [OpenMP 5.1](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf) one can read a more formal description :

> When a thread encounters a **parallel construct**, **a team of threads is
> created** to execute the parallel region (..). The
> thread that encountered the parallel construct becomes the primary
> thread of the new team, with a thread number of zero for the duration
> of the new parallel region. **All threads in the new team, including the
> primary thread, execute the region.** Once the team is created, the
> number of threads in the team remains constant for the duration of
> that parallel region.

The `#pragma omp parallel for` creates a `parallel region` (as described before), and to the `threads` of that region the iterations of the loop that it encloses will be assigned, using the `default chunk size`, and the `default schedule` which is *typically* `static`. Bear in mind, however, that the `default schedule` might differ among different concrete implementation of the `OpenMP` standard.

From the [OpenMP 5.1](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf) you can read a more formal description :

> The worksharing-loop construct specifies that the iterations of one or
> more associated loops will be executed in parallel by threads in the
> team in the context of their implicit tasks. **The iterations are
> distributed across threads that already exist in the team that is
> executing the parallel region to which the worksharing-loop region
> binds**.

[Moreover](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf),

> The parallel loop construct is a shortcut for specifying a parallel
> construct containing a loop construct with one or more associated
> loops and no other statements.

Or informally, `#pragma omp parallel for` is a combination of the constructor `#pragma omp parallel` with `#pragma omp for`. In your case, this would mean that:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {

    double r=0.0;
    for (int i=0; i < m; i++){

        double rand_g1 = cos(i/double(m));
        double rand_g2 = sin(i/double(m));     

        x += rand_g1;
        y += rand_g2;
        r += sqrt(rand_g1*rand_g1 + rand_g2*rand_g2);
    }
    shifts[j] = r / m;
}
```

A team of threads will be created, and to each of those threads will be assigned chunks of the iterations of the outermost loop.

To make it more illustrative, with `4` threads the `#pragma omp parallel for` with a `chunk_size=1` and a *static* `schedule` would result in something like:

(**attention**: the 'i' on the image referes to the 'j' in the code)

[image]

Code-wise the loop would be transformed to something *logically* similar to:

```
for(int j=omp_get_thread_num(); j < n; j+=omp_get_num_threads())
{  
    c[j]=a[j]+b[j];
}
```

where [omp_get_thread_num()](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu113.html)

> The omp_get_thread_num routine returns the thread number, within the
> current team, of the calling thread.

and [omp_get_num_threads()](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu113.html)

> Returns the number of threads in the current team. In a sequential
> section of the program omp_get_num_threads returns 1.

or in other words, `for(int i = THREAD_ID; i < n; i += TOTAL_THREADS)`. With `THREAD_ID` ranging from `0` to `TOTAL_THREADS - 1`, and `TOTAL_THREADS` representing the total number of threads of the team created on the parallel region.

Armed with this knowledge, and looking at your code, one can see that you have a *race-condition* on the updates of the variables 'x' and 'y'. Those variables are shared among threads and update inside the parallel region, namely:

```
     x += rand_g1;
     y += rand_g2;
```

To solve this race-condition you can use OpenMP' [reduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-clauses?view=msvc-160#reduction) clause:

> Specifies that one or more variables that are private to each thread
> are the subject of a reduction operation at the end of the parallel
> region.

Informally, the reduction clause, will create for each thread a private copy of the variables 'x' and 'y', and at the end of the parallel region perform the summation among all those 'x' and 'y' variables into the original 'x' and 'y' variables from the initial thread.

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:x,y)
for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {

    double r=0.0;
    for (int i=0; i < m; i++){

        double rand_g1 = cos(i/double(m));
        double rand_g2 = sin(i/double(m));     

        x += rand_g1;
        y += rand_g2;
        r += sqrt(rand_g1*rand_g1 + rand_g2*rand_g2);
    }
    shifts[j] = r / m;
}
```

Comment: Probably the illustration (thread0: for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 4)) is not accurate because this scheme will cause cache line invalidation of different threads. More likely openmp will do: for (int i = 0; i < n /4; i += 1)

Comment: @SteveZ, if the chunk=1 it is really like the image, you can quickly confirm this by printing the thread's ID and the value of variable 'i'.

Comment: No, it is not the image. For the OP's code, If you "cout << j << ": " << omp_get_thread_num() << "\n";" after "shifts[j] = r/ m", the first 30 j's thread id are all 0.  compiled with "g++ -O3 -std=c++17 test_omp.cpp -o test_omp -fopenmp" @dreamcrash

Comment: yep, because in the OP code uses the default chunk, which will split the iterations as blocks among the threads

Comment: @SteveZ After having a look at the image again, what is misleading is the fact that the image uses 'i', but in reality I should be using 'j' the loop being parallelized

Answer (score -3):

What you can achieve at most(!) is a linear speedup.
Now I don't remember which is which with the times from linux, but I'd suggest you to use time.h or (in c++ 11) "chrono" and measure the runtime directly from the programm. Best pack the entire code into a loop, run it 10 times and average to get approx runtime by the prog.

Furthermore you've got imo a problem with x,y - which do not adhere to the paradigm of data locality in parallel programming.

Comment: "What you can achieve at most(!) is a linear speedup." - Wrong! With proper local data access patterns superlinear speedups are often observed for embarrassingly parallel problems like this one because more data fits in the combined CPU cache.